# Excess intermediate storing instruction in integer addition

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

Background:
GCC 6.1 at `-O3` optimisation level generates this assembly:

```
    test    ecx, ecx
    je      .L8
    xor     r8d, r8d
    xor     eax, eax

.L7:
    xor     r9d, r9d
    add     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+r8*4]     ; adding a[i]
    setc    r9b
    add     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi+r8*4]     ; adding b[i]
    mov     r11d, eax                     ; excessive mov (#1)
    setc    r10b
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdx+r8*4], r11d    ; storing at s[i]
    add     r8, 1
    movzx   r10d, r10b
    cmp     ecx, r8d
    lea     eax, [r10+r9]                 ; sorcery (#2)
    ja      .L7
    rep ret

.L8:
    xor     eax, eax
    ret
```

for this function:

```
limb_t add(
    const limb_t *a,
    const limb_t *b,
    limb_t *s,
    int n
) {
    limb_t c = 0, t = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        t = a[i] + c;
        c = t < a[i];

        t += b[i];
        c += t < b[i];

        s[i] = t;
    }

    return c;
}
```

where `a`, `b` and `s` are integers of equal length `n` limbs, stored in memory as a continuous sequence of 32 bit units (limbs, digits) in Little Endian (that is, the first one being the least significant limb).

This function adds two non-negative addends `a` and `b`, stores the sum in `s`, and returns the carry `c`. Temporary variable `t` holds current sum limb, and enables `a == s` and `b == s` scenarios.

As I deduced from the assembly,

- `rdi` register holds base address of `a` addend,
- `rsi` register holds base address of `b` addend,
- `rdx` register holds base address of `s`, sum,
- `eax` register accounts for both `c`, carry, and `t`, temporary,
- `r8` register holds `i`, loop counter,
- `ecx` register holds `n`, length in limbs of addends and sum.

---

My first question is:

**1. Why does intermediate storing of `eax` register value in `r11d` register take place before moving it to memory `[rdx + r8*4]` (current limb of sum)?**

I don't see any other usage of `r11` register, but for this excessive store operation; and `mov` instruction actually allows moving from `eax` register, why not move the value from there?

---

My second question is:

**2. What is this sorcery with `lea` instruction and carry values?**

```
    lea     eax, [r10+r9]                 ; sorcery (#2)
```

What does it actually calculate? `lea` = `r10` + `r9`? And, in this case, why do we have to clear high bits of `r10` each loop iteration with this `movzx` instruction?

```
    movzx   r10d, r10b
```

Comment: Did you benchmark against the code you think is better? What was the result? Why do you bother? Did you check the instruction timing of exactly that sequence vs. your "better" code (including register renaming, pipeline-stalls, setc.)?

Comment: Well, it is really challenging to write such high-level C code that would compile to efficient enough assembly. I thought, maybe it was something I did in the source code that results in this suboptimal assembly. Quite simple tweaks of *generated* assembly could decrease number of instructions per loop iteration from current 13 to 8 by scoping excess registers clearing out of cycle, replacing `setc` and `add` with `adc` (as suggested by @Jester) and removing intermediate `r11` storage.

Comment: The only way to test it is to code it as inline assembly and run against the version generated by GCC, and I did not go that far yet. The question was **why compiler whould do such things, maybe generated code could be backed up by some rational reasons I have no knowledge of**. I guess the best way to go about writing the most efficient code is to thoroughly investigate the assembly provided by GMP or OpenSSL for this kind of stuff.

Comment: You missed my point! It is not guaranteed less instructions are faster! x86 is the most complex architecture. Worse, as there are at least 2 manufacturers, code which run on Intel does not necessarily perform equally well on AMD or vice versa. The question  "why do compiler do such things" is far too broad for this site. It would require to explain how a modern CISC (and some RISC) CPU works, how a compiler works, etc.  Just concluding from code-size to speed is nonsense (see the classical RISC vs CISC discussions).

Comment: Yes, I do understand that performance depends on a lot of other factors as well, such as execution order, latency, throughput and sequencing of  instructions, usage of execution units and i/o ports, behaviour of branch predictor and a lot of other things. I have a basic understanding of both how the code is compiled and how x86 architecture works. What I was asking is whether there is a specific reason I am not aware of why compiler would use `r11` register as intermediate storage for sum limb, that is all. And, according to @Jester's answer, that is just an imperfection of a compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first seems to be "missed optimization" compiler bug.

The second needs to produce `c` of size dword for the `t = a[i] + c;` and it does that by extending the two logical values, using different methods which is admittedly kind of strange:

`t < a[i];` is performed by `xor r9d, r9d` and `setc r9b` but `t < b[i]` is performed by the `setc r10b` and `movzx r10d, r10b` pair. It's not immediately obvious but this might have legitimate instruction scheduling reasons.

Adding the two logical values is accomplished by the `lea eax, [r10+r9]` which is used instead of `add` for two reasons. First, it doesn't affect flags so it can be inserted between the `cmp` and the `ja`. Second, it can produce output in a third register.

Another possibility would be to add the two logical values first and only extend the result. Not sure if that would be a better approach. Also, one temporary register would be enough.

Comment: Surely, `xor r9d, r9d` and `movzx r10d, r10b` could be carried out before the cycle? Is there any specific reason for executing them each iteration?

And could you please elaborate on *one temporary register*?

Comment: `xor` could be, but that's a dependency breaking idiom so might be worse. The `movzx` can't since that needs `r10b` which is set in the loop. The code uses `r9` and `r10` for the two logical values and puts their sum into `eax`. Could be done with the second value in `eax` so using one less register. Again, this might not be faster. x86 optimization is complicated :)

Comment: No, what I am saying is that it seems possible to clear the values of `r9` and `r10` carry registers in advance, because only the least significant bit could change in single loop iteration, and **there is no need to explicitly clear high bits of these registers within iterations via `xor X, X` or `movxz Xd, Xb`**.

Comment: Yes that's true, but then again you don't even need to clear the rest. You could add them first then zero extend. For example `setc r10b; ... ; setc r9b; ... lea eax, [r9+r10]; movzx eax, al`. You could also avoid the second `setc` and instead use an `adc` which already does both. Many ways, but hard to tell which is fastest.

Comment: Hold on, but if we don't clear high bits of `r9` and `r10` in advance (before cycle), then `lea eax, [r9 + r10]` could result in invalid `eax` carry value (invalid low byte of `eax`, that is), which, in general, should not be greater than 2 (literally), and this invalid carry would propagate to higher limbs. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, I see, `setc` instruction would set the whole byte to 0x00 or 0x01, that answers my previous question.